# how to check error conditions c#

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have group of conditions like

```
foreach
{
Condition a 
condition b
}
```

So I am validating the values based on conditions.I am facing the problem: for example I have list of items like {1,2,3,4}. So I have a condition like if item 1 is fail then item 2,3,4 should be fail.
     if item 2 is fail then item 3,4 should be fail and so on.

I am trying in below code.

```
 foreach (SagaData item in lstPrm)
                    {
                        PriceDetail prevPrice = null;
                        PriceDetail currentPrice = null;
                        PriceDetail nextPrice = null;
                        bool bHasError = false;
                        int iPriceMasterId = 0;
                        int iPriceTypeId = 0;
                        string sMprCurrencyType = null;
                        string sPublisherCurrencyType = null;
                        int? iExpirationCalendarId = 0;
                        string sPRMMessage = string.Empty;

                        //a)    If Change Indicator = C or A and Price = 0.00: Cannot change price value to zero.
                        if ((item.ChangeIndicator == 'C' || item.ChangeIndicator == 'A') && item.PostingPrice == 0)
                        {
                            bHasError = true;
                            sPRMMessage = "FAILURECannot change price value to zero";
                        }

                        //b)    If Change Indicator = D and Price > 0.00: Invalid deactivation.
                        if ((item.ChangeIndicator == 'D') && (item.PostingPrice > 0) && (!bHasError))
                        {
                            bHasError = true;
                            sPRMMessage = "FAILUREInvalid deactivation";
                        }
```

so i have if condition a fail for item 1 then how should i keep maintain the error for next iteration.
Thanks for the help. if you want more info plz let me know.

Comment: Move `bool bHasError = false;` outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks its working

Comment: Who is doing -1

Comment: Voting is anonymous. There is no way for you to see who is doing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through your Collection with a simple for loop and use an ErrorArray:

```
bool[] bHasError = new bool[lstPrm.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < lstPrm.Count; i++)
{
   ...
   bHasError[i] = true;
   ...
}
```

or you can define bHasError BEFORE the foreach if one error is enough for you to consider.